# ArrayList as a templatized class

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and need to create a templatized class that implements an Array List. It needs a bunch of member functions that I am fairly certain I have correct but am unsure about the copy constructor and assignment operator.

I have been staring at this code for hours and cannot figure out why it will not output correctly.

My output: [0,1,2,0,0,]

Desired output: [0,1,2,3,4,]

I think it is something to do with my assignment operator and copy constructor but I cannot figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template <typename Item>
class ArrayList {

private:
    Item *Array;
    size_t arrayLength;     // length of array
    size_t listSize;        // # elements in array

public:
    ArrayList(size_t asize=10) {
        // Set up array
        // Initialize parameters
        Array = new Item[asize + 1];
        arrayLength = asize;
        listSize = 0;

    }

    ~ArrayList()
    {
        delete [] Array;
    }

    ArrayList(const ArrayList &other)
    {
        arrayLength = other.arrayLength;
        listSize = other.listSize;
        Array = new Item[arrayLength+1];
        memcpy(Array, other.Array, arrayLength+1);
    }

    ArrayList& operator= (const ArrayList &other)
    {
        arrayLength = other.arrayLength;
        listSize = other.listSize;
        Array = new Item[arrayLength+1];
        memcpy(Array, other.Array, arrayLength+1);
        return *this;
    }

    bool needToResize(){
        return arrayLength == listSize;
    }

    void resize(){
        Item *temp = new Item[arrayLength * 2];
        for(size_t i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
            temp[i] = Array[i];
        }
        Array = temp;
        arrayLength *= 2;
    }

    void insertAt(Item a, size_t index = 0)
    {
        if(needToResize()){
            resize();
        }
        for(size_t i = listSize; i > index; i--){

            // index = 3
            // Item = 6

            //   0     1    2   3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
            // eggs   eggs  ___

            Array[i] = Array[i - 1];
        }
        Array[index] = a;
        listSize++;
    }

    Item& at(size_t index){
        return Array[index];
    }

    void remove(size_t index)
    {
        for(size_t i = index; i < arrayLength; i++){
            Array[i] = Array[i+1];

        }
        listSize--;

    }
    bool empty() {
        return listSize == 0;
    }
    size_t find(Item item)
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
            if(Array[i] == item){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    size_t size()
    {
        return listSize;
    }
};

// DO NOT MODIFY BELOW HERE
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, ArrayList<T> &array)
{
    out << "[";
    for (size_t i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
    {
        out << array.at(i) << ",";
    }
    out << "]";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    ArrayList<int> l;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        l.insertAt(i,l.size());

    ArrayList<int> l2 = l;

    cout << l2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy` copies bytes, your contents is `int`s which usually aren’t one byte each. That can easily make things go wrong. Also why the +1s?

Comment: Remove +1 everywhere. In memcpy you need to write arrayLength * sizeof Item

Comment: As others pointed out you need to take the size of items into consideration when you are copying. However while that will work for simple types like int you cannot memcpy objects because these may have custom assignment operators and copy constructors that must be used to make a valid copy.

Comment: `memcpy(Array, other.Array, arrayLength+1);` -- use `std::copy`, not `memcpy`.  Your class will fail miserably if you have `ArrayList<std::string>`, for example.